# QGIS 3.18 dyld: Symbol not found: __cg_jpeg_resync_to_restart

Tags: qgis, macos

MacOS High Sierra (10.13), QGIS 3.18 Zurich, GRASS 7.8, GDAL/OGR 2.4.1, Python 2.7

`DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` set to `"/Applications/QGIS-3.18.app/Contents/MacOS/lib"`

With a fresh installation of QGIS 3.18, when trying to create a VRT, the process return  :

```
GDAL command output :
dyld: Symbol not found: __cg_jpeg_resync_to_restart
Referenced from: /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/ImageIO
Expected in: /Applications/QGIS-3.18.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/libjpeg.9.dylib
in /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/ImageIO
/Applications/QGIS-3.18.app/Contents/MacOS/bin/run_gdal_binary.bash: line 13: 77707 Abort trap: 6 "$THISDIR/_$ALGNAME" "$@"
Process return code error 134
```

The 3 path exported by run_gdal_binary.bash exist.

Noticed that `libjpeg.9.dylib` is linked by `libjpeg.dylib`

GRASS warn that `"Module built against version 2021-02-10T17:13:06+00:00 but trying to use version 2021-02-10T17:08:53+00:00. You need to rebuild GRASS GIS or untangle multiple installations."` although it has been installed just once a week ago.

Trying to merge DEM produces a larger output where appears the same reference to `"Symbol not found: __cg_jpeg_resync_to_restart"` and other python error.

What went wrong? QGIS? Dynamic library? Something broken in Python script?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get saga tools working by replacing the links to the system files that are referenced in the error logs:

```bsh
cd /Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/lib
rm libjpeg.dylib
ln -s /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Resources/libJPEG.dylib libJPEG.dylib
rm libtiff.dylib
ln -s /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Resources/libTIFF.dylib libTIFF.dylib
rm libpng.dylib
ln -s /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Resources/libPng.dylib libPng.dylib
rm libsqlite3.dylib
ln -s /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreData.framework/Versions/A/CoreData/libsqlite3.dylib libsqlite3.dylib
```

note:
the first cd command needs to use the correct directory for $DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH, so OP needs to use /Applications/QGIS-3.18.app/Contents/MacOS/lib

via:
https://root-forum.cern.ch/t/root-breakdown-after-mac-upgrade/27234/2
which was via:
http://diana.parno.net/thoughts/?p=192

Comment: There is already links in /Applications/QGIS-3.18.app/Contents/MacOS/lib :

Comment: yes, for me they all needed to be removed and recreated (thus the rm commands)

Answer (score 0):

In short, IT WORKS!

In a more precise way, lets have more explanations.

There is already links in `/Applications/QGIS-3.18.app/Contents/MacOS/lib`:

```
libjpeg.dylib -> libjpeg.9.dylib, 
libpng.dylib -> libpng16.16.dylib, 
libpng16.dylib -> libpng16.16.dylib, 
libtiff.dylib -> libtiff.5.dylib,
```

We can note the case differences in the files names between the Qgis files names and the system lib files names. First removing the originals links in Qgis.
So, making the symlink i did change the case in eg.: `libJPEG.dylib` by `libjpeg.dylib`

```
ln -s /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Resources/libJPEG.dylib libjpeg.dylib
```

Running Qgis, the create VRT command works.

(Been long to answer and try the trick because i have been too busy or outside faraways without a Mac)

Comment: why did you choose to make a new answer instead of commenting and accepting my answer (https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/398282/81215)?

Comment: Simply because the comment it did wrote was too long and rejected.